# Android cannot resolve symbol: Context.BATTERY_SERVICE

Tags: android, batterymanager

for an App I need to monitor the Average battery current in micro amperes. I did it like described here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/index.html#device-power

```
private long getPowerConsumption() {
    BatteryManager mBatteryManager;
    mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
    long energy = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER);
    return energy;
}
```

But I'm getting a "Cannot resolve symbol BATTERY_SERVICE".

The context is a reference to an Activity.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `import android.os.ServiceManager;` ?

Comment: it looks like this was added in API 21 - make sure your project's tartgetSDK level is at least 21

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not somewhere else in your code? The BATTERY_SERVICE in Context is public and static. It's possible that your IDE can't find it because there is another error in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BATTERY_SERVICE` was added in API Level 21. Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21, and ensure that you only go through this code on API Level 21+ devices.

Comment: and how to establish that for android before 21?

Comment: @DiaaSaada: Sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. I meant what if my app should support android 19, what should I do can u point me to a reference.

Comment: @DiaaSaada: AFAIK, you do not have access to this information on API Level 19.